# CouchDB: Create/Update/Delete if new, modified or removed

Tags: couchdb

I´m doing nightly data synchronisation where I pull out *complete* set of documents from the source/master through REST API and update slave destination which is a CouchDB.

The data load is pretty small, maximum 100 JSON documents. Update frequency in master is expected to be 1-2 times in week for couple of documents.

Following changes can occur:

- document is removed
- document is added
- data in existing document is changed

Does CouchDB provide any out-of-box bulk operation for doing create/update/delete based on the document collection sent in and automatically checks if the documents are new/changed/removed? If not, what would be a good approach to implement this myself?

*Edit:*
I just found two useful npm modules for comparing json in source and destination. For those of you interestes in the solution of this question.

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-diff
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsondiffpatch

Comment: So your source is not a CouchDB or compatible database? If it was, you could use replication, which does exactly what you describe.

Comment: Unfortunately I can access source data only through a REST API that I don´t have any control over and it doesn´t seems to be a CouchDB either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your data-set is small, I would recommend just using the [bulk documents API](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/api/database/bulk-api.html#db-bulk-docs).

You can just use `_all_docs` to retrieve your entire data-set, store that in memory and do your "does this exist" and "what has changed" checks all in-place. At the end, just send the entire 100 documents via `_bulk_docs`.

If your CouchDB just keeps growing (ie: it's not always going to be 100 docs) then you could always write up a few views that you can use to check for add/update on a specific data-item.

Comment: So the logic for checking if exists and if changed needs to be custom made. No support from the CouchDB API? Another (little bit off topic) question: would you recommend to consume the  CouchDB API directly from code in NodeJS or by use of some CouchDB node module?

Comment: Correct, you can write views that you can query, but it won't be an operation from within CouchDB itself.

Comment: I pretty much always recommend using modules, writing your own boilerplate from scratch isn't worth your time.

Comment: Any specific module you would recommend?

Comment: If you're using the changes feed, check out [follow](https://www.npmjs.com/package/follow), for general API usage I have a [module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/couchdb-api) as well.

Comment: Do you have any experience with [Nano](https://github.com/dscape/nano) or [Cradle](https://github.com/flatiron/cradle)?

Comment: Nope, but they are both solid libraries.